# MySQL table "doesn't exist" error

Tags: mysql, windows-7, restore, reinstall

I'm using Windows 7 Ultimate x64. After reinstalling OS copied back whole MySQL data directory to `C:/Programdata`. But now when i'm trying to open some table from restored db's with Navicat it shows me http://prntscr.com/2s9wl error. I don't know what to do. Please help.

Comment: Nothing, except it belongs on http://serverfault.com Q&A for system administrators and desktop support professionals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the *correct* way to backup a database in MySQL is the mysqldump.

This http://www.softwareprojects.com/resources/programming/t-how-to-fix-mysql-database-myisam-innodb-1634.html step-through-step troubleshooting text is unix-centric, but it should be very similar for the Windows world.

Good luck.